# Choose which activity to start on app initializing?

Tags: java, android

It was hard to summarize the problem in the title but it's really not very complicated.

My problem is this: After installing an app you see an "Open app" button on the play store which initiates your app similarly to when you click run on Eclipse. When you do either of these things the first launcher activity found in the manifest is brought to started.

For example if this were my manifest:

```
    <!-- Home screen replacemnt -->
    <activity
        android:name=".launcher" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Launcher Application -->
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

When open was clicked `SettingsActivity` would be started since the first activity isn't a launcher app.

My problem is that the first time users open my app I want them to see the launcher. how do I make sure `.launcher` is started when my application is opened?

Answer (score 2):

You should *not* distinguish this based on the Intent level. Instead, have a [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) file for your app, in which you write an integer representing the version if it does not yet exist resp. indicates an older version. Then, based on that mechanism, you implement your "first time install" and/or "first run after update" logic.

Comment: I'm already doing this actually. I have a baseactivity which all extend so I could onstart bring users to the launcher. I thought there was an easier method though

Comment: If you have a shared preferences file in place which also contains a version information, then it should be easyenough. Although I agree that it's not too obvious etc. But at least more flexible and more powerful. ;)

Comment: I found a problem with this idea, or maybe I didn't get it right. I added a few lines that check if it's the first launch in all my activities, if it is it takes the user to the launcher. This worked until I realised that if the user DOESN'T clicks "open app" and instead clicks an icon for an activity like eg: settings. He also is taken to the launcher. Do you get what I mean?

Comment: I'm trying to think of a solution, but I don't see how to differenciate if Settings has been started from it's icon or from the "Open button". Does this has to do with the "Intent level" you mentioned?

Comment: @Liso22 I thought this was the deal: That _all_ "first times" the user is taken to the launcher. Why does this have to be different depending on whether the user starts your app for the first time from the installer or afterwards? I don't see how this would be justified? But either way, did you experiment with a third activity and _Intent.CATEGORY_PREFERENCE_?

Comment: No, I didn't, I'll try that as soon as I can. This is the deal: there is a button to "Open my app" in the store, when the user clicks it he expects to see the launcher, after all the app is called EasyLauncher. But there are also individual icons like eg: Settings. If the user doesn't click Open app and instead later clicks on the Settings icon he should be taken to Settings.

Comment: Could you get what I meant? I was also a bit confused about how to implement this. Creating a third activity without an icon will probably fix the issue.

Comment: @Liso22 I must say it would have helped (maybe even you) to try and put it in pseudo code. I think I understand your objectives. I tend to think,. though, that I would actually _expect_ a complex software such as a launcher to confront me with a setup screen if it's complex enough; even if that screen has a big green "spare me the details, I wanna see it" button upfront. ;)

Comment: @Liso22 So, did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

you have to delete intent filter from SettingsActivity

To resolve redirecting user there is many solutions:
1- You can use two different method, Add a SplashScreen activity and add you Logic to determine next Activity.
2- Add non visible UI Activity as You main Activity, for more detail see this tutorial:
[TranscludeActivity](http://derekknox.com/daklab/2012/04/18/tutorial-how-to-create-invisible-apps-in-android)

3- Make luncher you main Activity, after that, within the onCreate method, test if Settings existe, if not start SettingsActivity and call to finish();